# Can you install the desktop OS using sd card?

Tags: sd-card

Trying to install Ubuntu OS on a new hard drive. Can it be done from my sd card?

Comment: yes you can, just burn the iso on your sd card and boot from it. I installed my current ubuntu from a sd card inserted in a usb stick. If you have an other hd I suggest your to make a backup or disconnect it.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS & architecture details, so responses can only be generic, but yes you can use any media your hardware will boot from (ie. it'll depend on your box hardware & firmware).

Comment: You can create an installer SD card using Rufus, Etcher, Ventoy, mkusb, Gnome-Disks, dd or Startup Disk Creator

Comment: @C.S.Cameron If you copy/paste the above comment as an answer to the linked duplicate question I'll upvote it. Maybe add some download links to the answer if necessary..

Answer (score 1):

### Tools to Create an Installer SD Card

You can create an installer SD card using **Rufus** - https://rufus.ie/, **Etcher** - https://www.balena.io/etcher/, **Ventoy** - https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html, or **YUMI** - https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ in Windows.

In Ubuntu you can use **Gnome-Disks**, **dd** and **Startup Disk Creator**, they are built into Ubuntu. My favorite is **mkusb** - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui